# django getattr and issues with updating

Tags: python, django, django-models, getattr

In django I built a simple method that gets called and is passed a uniqueid, field specifier, and a value. It then does a simple addition to update the value in the field. I've coded it a number of ways and have come to the conclusion that getattr does not work when trying to save, update, or refresh the database. 
One variation of my code:

```
def updatetable(uid, fieldtitle, value):
    workingobj = bog_db.objects.get(name=uid)
    objectcall = getattr(workingobj,fieldtitle)
    objectcall = F(fieldtitle) + value
    workingobj.refresh_from_db()
    return
```

I tried hand jamming some code to see if I could figure out the problem. 
btw: value = 37

```
In [36]: call = getattr(workingobj,fieldname)

In [37]: call
Out[37]: 37

In [38]: call += value

In [39]: call
Out[39]: 74

In [40]: workingobj.save()
#refreshed database, checked table, values in db not updated
In [41]: workingobj.total_number_posts += value

In [42]: workingobj.total_number_posts
Out[42]: 74

In [43]: workingobj.save()
#refreshed database, values in db were updated
```

It would appear to me that Django does not want you using getattr for doing db calls and updates and instead wants you to EXPLICITLY call object.field.

Is this true? Does getattr make a copy of the attributes? I want to better understand why it is behaving this way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're expecting here, but this is nothing to do with Django wanting anything, and nothing to do with `setattr`.

Integers are immutable. However you get the value of fieldname and store it in `call`, you cannot modify it. Doing `call += value` creates a new value and stores it in `call`; that now has no relationship with the original value of fieldname.

Note that you would get *exactly* the same result if you originally did `call = workingobj.fieldname`.

Comment: I was trying to use getattr as a way to be able to write a simple update method that I could call and pass fields to and have it do simple math. I've since tweaked the code to just use two different methods with the fields explicitly reference. I was thinking getattr would actually access the attribute and not make a copy of it. I see what you mean now that I take a better look at the code. Thanks.

Comment: Ultimately I ended up figuring out that part of my problem was I was missing from project.models import models. That helped me in being able to pass model objects as variables. Then I came up with a combination of getattr and setattr to be able to update the variables.